# Tag cleanup: Delete tag combine

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

There are around 40 questions with the tag [combine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/combine).

Some of them is related to combining, merging items, for some I don't know why they're tagged.

I don't think this tag would add to the value of the questions, also I couldn't find any common of the questions with this tag.

I suggest to delete this tag.

Comment: I agree with this. The combine is like a help tag: just useless.